# Input string was not in a correct format & how to rename rowheader datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, sql-update, vb.net-2010

please code solution and for rename row header I mean marking the color of the image file I attached
Note : for notes I use visual studio 2010

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        dbConnection()
        Dim indexID As Integer
        x = DataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)
        indexID = Convert.ToInt32((DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString()))

        sql = "UPDATE ITEM SET ITM= '" & txtFname.Text & "',ITC='" & txtLname.Text & "',QOH='" & cbGender.Text & "' WHERE ID=" & indexID & ""

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated...", "Update")
        conn.Close()

        'btnReadDatabase_Click(sender, e);
        retrieveALL()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Input string was not in a correct format]
[image: Rename rowheader]
[image: datagridview]
[object reference not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJrtg.jpg)
Thanks
roy

Comment: The red circle in the picture appears to be a “row header” and technically is NOT column[0] in the grid. The `ITM` column appears to be column zero (0). Therefore, the error appears fairly clear as “ROY RSL 10000” is not a valid `int32` value … hence the error.

Comment: @JohnG , thanks for your reply, so how to code solution?

Comment: To get the row header text may look something like... `dataGridView1.Rows[x].HeaderCell.Value.ToString();`

Comment: `indexID = Convert.ToInt32((DataGridView1.Rows(x).HeaderCell.Value.ToString()))'    I change according to you then there is an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Well… if one of the rows does not have any header text or possibly if it is the “new” row… then … `dataGridView1.Rows[x].HeaderCell.Value` … may be `null/Nothing`… so your code needs to check this `null` value before you try and grab the `Value.ToString()`. `If (dataGridView1.Rows[x].HeaderCell.Value IsNot Nothing) Then…`

Comment: actually what result u want from that code

Comment: It would be much simpler if you included your IndexID in the DataGridView but as a hidden column.  You can then access the column by name and avoid all these problems.

Comment: @JohnG , `If (DataGridView1.Rows(x).HeaderCell.Value IsNot Nothing) Then
            indexID = Convert.ToInt32((DataGridView1.Rows(x).HeaderCell.Value.ToString()))` What's like this you mean.Thanks for your reply. I haven't succeeded. if there is a purpose like this or you can answer in full code from the one I posted

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 , I want to do an update via oledb and also give a title on the rowheader that I circle in red

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , You can provide a solution with code.

Comment: I would do as @Jonathan Willcock suggest without “hiding” the column. I am just saying that… `IF` the text in the header row is “actually” an index from the DB… `THEN` … you “must” have written extra code to “add” that data to the row header cell and as a side effect… your current dilemma. Keep it simple… Make the “ID” as a regular column unless there is “some” specific reason you must have that data in the row header. Using the row header as you are is only complicating things and creates more work for you. I can assure you the user won’t care one way or the other.

Comment: @JohnG , Thank you for your reply, I follow your recommendation. How is the code solution and can you make an answer?. I mean I have to add you as a column made as column id . Can it be without additional id columns?

Comment: then you take DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).RowIndex it show selected row index value by default integer.

Comment: @JohnG , What's the code solution because it's still a problem?

Comment: [edit] your question and "ADD" your updated code and the error you are getting. If you are still keeping the text in the header cell, then your biggest problem is that you need to check numerous things before you call `DataGridView1.Rows(x).HeaderCell.Value.ToString()` ... currently your code does not check anything and this can lead to exceptions.

Comment: @JohnG , I've updated code but no results or any updates may be wrong with the code I updated

Comment: I see the update but what is the error? If you are not getting any results from the sql query then I am guessing that the `sql` string is missing the single quote … ‘ … around the variable `indexID`. … `… WHERE ID=" & indexID & ""` … should be … `… WHERE ID=’" & indexID & "’"`. … However I could be mistaken about this.

Comment: @JohnG , ok I've updated sql according to you. results no errors but no updates

Comment: @JohnG , I didn't get any results.

Comment: Since you are not getting any errors and the data is not updated in the DB, then, I can only assume the `sql` query is not inserting as expected. I would guess that your DB would return a value indicating how many rows were affected by the query. Something like… `int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` … if it returns zero (0), then the insert is failing for some reason. I suggest you copy the `sql` string and run it directly from the DB.

Comment: @JohnG , I have updated the code from you that c# then I changed it to vb.net but not the result and I also updated the save code button that to add the record was no problem and there was a result.

Comment: Sorry but your last comment is not understandable. What happens when you paste the `sql` query string into the DB and run it? It appears pretty clear that something is wrong with it.

Comment: @JohnG, I don't understand what you mean? Can you set an example to me?

Comment: @JohnG , I mean my last comment is sql command for insert record can be done

Comment: Hmmm… an example for what? Your question started with how to get the header row text and has evolved it something else. We do not have your DB, so only you can test to see if the query in your code is correct. If the DB does not get updated using your code, then you need to find out why. In the button click event… put a break-point on the line … `cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)` … then look at the `sql` `string` and copy it. Then go to your DB and paste that string into the query window and run it... you may get a better idea of “why” the query failed.

Comment: If you run the query in the DB’s query window, then, it “should” tell you “why” the query failed. I would guess the only reason for the query to fail would be if `indexID` was not found in the table. I suggest you look closely at the `indexID` variable and make sure it matches at least one `ID` in the DB. As I said, this is something only YOU can do since we do not have your DB.

Comment: @JohnG , I've updated sql that directly updates to the database still no results whatsoever. You can see the code update post from me. indexid you mean, I explained that I do not have an id in db (database)

Comment: _”I explained that I do not have an id in db (database)”_ … ? … then how would you expect … `… & "' WHERE ID='" & indexID & "'"` … to work?

Comment: @JohnG , sorry so I mean the id is not a number, if you look in the itm column in the datagridview screenshot "ROY RSL 10000 RC" this is my id or it can be said text/string

Comment: @JohnG , I know the problem is if I use an Access database which has a primary key with an auto number, there is no problem with the SQL update, but the problem is that the DBF database does not have a primary key with an auto number. So what's the solution?

Comment: @JohnG , is there any solution?

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 ,I know the problem is if I use an Access database which has a primary key with an auto number, there is no problem with the SQL update, but the problem is that the DBF database does not have a primary key with an auto number. So what's the solution?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock , I know the problem is if I use an Access database which has a primary key with an auto number, there is no problem with the SQL update, but the problem is that the DBF database does not have a primary key with an auto number. So what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    dbConnection()
    sql = "UPDATE ITEM SET ITM= '" & txtFname.Text & "',ITC='" & txtLname.Text & "',QOH='" & cbGender.Text & "' WHERE ITC='" & txtLname.Text & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated...", "Update")
    con.Close()
    PopulateDataGridView()
End Sub
```